# Solution of trigonometric equation $\sin(n\theta)-2\sin(2\theta)\cos(n\theta)=0$

Tags: trigonometry

I have the following equations.
\begin{align}
& n\theta+\phi=j\pi,\text{ for some }j\in\mathbb{Z},\\
& 2\sin(\theta+\phi)=k(4\cos^2\theta-1)\text{ and }\\
& 2k\cos\theta=\sin\phi.
\end{align}
I eliminate $k$ and $\phi$ from these equations and get
\begin{align}\sin(n\theta)-2\sin(2\theta)\cos(n\theta)=0\end{align} where $n\in\mathbb{N}$. 
Now I want to find the solution of the above equation.

Comment: I was trying some system of equations. Finally, I have eliminated all other variables and stuck at this point. I am not sure whether an explicit solution to the above equation is possible or not?

Comment: If you edit the question to show those equations and the place where you got stuck, you might get better quality answers. (No promises.)

Comment: $$\sin(n\theta)-2\sin(2\theta)\cos(n\theta)=0\\\to \div \cos(n\theta) \to \\
\tan(n\theta)=2\sin(2\theta)$$